# jQuery event will only run once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [table2excel](https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel) plugin which will allow me to download a tables contents to an excel file. It works fine the first time but it only lets me download once per page load.

I have tried changing the `$("#export").click(function(){` to `$("#export").on('click', function(){` but this did not work. The $('#export').click is within a doc ready

```
// click function on page
$("#export").click(function(){
  $("#table2excel").table2excel({
    // exclude CSS class
    exclude: ".noExl",
    name: "Excel Document Name"
  }); 
});

// external js file that gets called
//table2excel.js
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
        var pluginName = "table2excel",
                defaults = {
                exclude: ".noExl",
                name: "Table2Excel"
        };

        // The actual plugin constructor
        function Plugin ( element, options ) {
                this.element = element;
                // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
                // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
                // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
                // future instances of the plugin
                this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
                this._defaults = defaults;
                this._name = pluginName;
                this.init();
        }

        Plugin.prototype = {
            init: function () {
                var e = this;
                e.template = "<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>";
                e.template += "<x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions>";
                e.template += "<x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>";
                e.tableRows = "";

                // get contents of table except for exclude
                $(e.element).find("tr").not(this.settings.exclude).each(function (i,o) {
                    e.tableRows += "<tr>" + $(o).html() + "</tr>";
                });
                this.tableToExcel(this.tableRows, this.settings.name);
            },
            tableToExcel: function (table, name) {
                var e = this;
                e.uri = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,";
                e.base64 = function (s) {
                    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
                };
                e.format = function (s, c) {
                    return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                        return c[p];
                    });
                };
                e.ctx = {
                    worksheet: name || "Worksheet",
                    table: table
                };
                window.location.href = e.uri + e.base64(e.format(e.template, e.ctx));
            }
        };

        $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
                this.each(function() {
                        if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                                $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
                        }
                });

                // chain jQuery functions
                return this;
        };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: Is the click callback triggered on subsequent clicks (after the initial click)? Can you share a sandbox where this is reproducible?

Comment: Check for console errors; if your browser catches one while running a function, it will prevent any subsequent calls from running. In Firefox or Chrome, press `F12` to open the developer tools, and check the `console` tab when pressing `export`.

Comment: Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/puqxvrqu/

Comment: I've never used the plugin, but it sounds interesting indeed, but I was just wondering are you using the same file name for the 2nd click as well. If so can you some try with a different name, like adding some index value to the name. The index value could be changed after each click index + 1 or sth similar.

Comment: wow, thanks for the fiddle. Now I tested it -  my first ever excel created file via Web browser :-)

Comment: Not sure how it works exactly but the file name gets incremented i.e. download, download(1), download(2) etc

Comment: update with a working jsfiddle in below answer

Comment: @peterdotjs sorry wasn't on for a few days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only executes once because of this code block in the jquery plugin:

```
$.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
this.each(function() {
    if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
        $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
    }
});

// chain jQuery functions
return this;
```

};

`$("#table2excel")` is only initialized once and skipped subsequent times.

Made some changes to some changes to your code:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var $table = $('#table2excel');
    $table.removeData(); //data is removed, previous when data existed was preventing initialization of table2excel
    $table.table2excel({
        exclude: ".noExl",
        name: "Excel Document Name"
    }); 
});
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/peterdotjs/bpLsrdy2/4/

Answer (score 0):

Other then

```
$("#export").click(function(){
 $("#table2excel").table2excel({
 // exclude CSS class
  exclude: ".noExl",
  name: "Excel Document Name"
```

}); 
});

What do you hope to happen differently if they click it the second time?

What you may be feeling is only working once, is that it has applied the changes so it has no other actions to do as the work is done if clicked again.

This is under the assumption that the script is constantly going without errors. If there were errors, how you can check is by pressing f12 in Chrome. and in the top right corner of the screen you should see if there are errors. If it is running and then during the clicking action it fails, this could be your source to finding the problem.

Comment: Im looking it to fire off another excel doc creation

Comment: Also note that if the function is depending on another function later, JS scripts are read periodically.

Comment: Have you considered browser protection against multiple downloads? Btw Tried it in IE and not responding. FYI

Answer (score 0):

The plaguing according to script (jquery.table2excel.js) don't let you to run it more than once so for resolve this problem first add
to end of your file scrip  and after page loaded add link to the script which refer to plaguing now u can write your function to call exporting to excel

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#MyplaginEXL").attr("src","/TableToExcel/jquery.table2excel.js")
        });


    function PrintTable()
        {
      
            $("#IdTable").table2excel({
                exclude: ".noExl",
                filename: "FileName",
                fileext: ".xls",
                exclude_img: true,
                exclude_links: true,
                exclude_inputs: true,
                preserveColors: true
        });
     
    }
```